# Paperclip in rails 3, cannot use styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the following tuto http://www.jameswilding.net/blog/2010/07/paperclip-rails-3/ to have paperclip working on my rails app.
The think is... the item creation does not work when I specified the "styles" in my model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :pict, :styles => { :small  => "150x150>" }
  validates_attachment_presence :pict
  validates_attachment_size :pict, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :pict, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
end
```

On the form, I pick up a photo and then when I hit the 'create item' button, I have the following error (error that is not there anymore if I do not specify any styles in the model).

```
Started POST "/pictures" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 24 14:39:15 +0100 2011
Processing by PicturesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Picture",       "authenticity_token"=>"ZRTdrxt0d84D2WZvOXcOaRStcjmXazZBLRjtCmTsNKU=", "utf8"=>"✓", "picture"=>{"pict"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x1041869d8 @original_filename="IMG_0016.JPG", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[pict]\"; filename=\"IMG_0016.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/Hi/HiUKqJ7THYS7P-0e1NyczE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110324-1930-d28tly-0>, @content_type="image/jpeg">}}
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/Hi/HiUKqJ7THYS7P-0e1NyczE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110324-1930-1bxai3m-0.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Luc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant really make out whats going wrong.. But have u installed ImageMagick? It doesnt mention it in the blog but u need it to resize the pictures.

Comment: hmmm... I did not install imagemagick in fact. You'r right, this might be the piece missing. In the error message I have, we see Paperclip encounter a command not found error but it's not detailled...

Comment: sudo port install ImageMagick fixed the thing. Thanks a lot